# Injecting P6Spy in JBoss results in "Wrong driver class [class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] for this connection URL"

Tags: java, jboss, modeshape, p6spy

I'm currently debugging an application deployed over JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA and I want to use [P6Spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) to check what the database returns. I downloaded the files [from Maven](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/p6spy/p6spy/3.9.1/p6spy-3.9.1.zip) and followed [the instructions](https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#jboss-7-1-x-wildfly-8-x-wildfly-10-x), which were:

- Create a module in `/usr/local/jboss6/modules/com/p6spy/main/` containing the P6Spy JAR and the `module.xml`

  ```xml
  <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.p6spy">
      <resources>
          <resource-root path="p6spy-3.9.1.jar"/>
      </resources>
      <dependencies>
          <module name="javax.api"/>
          <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
          <!-- make sure to refer to module holding real driver -->
          <module name="com.mysql"/>
      </dependencies>
  </module>
  ```
- Create a `spy.properties` in the same folder (for ease of access) with the contents

  ```
  modulelist=com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyFactory,com.p6spy.engine.logging.P6LogFactory
  driverlist=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  autoflush=true
  reloadproperties=true
  reloadpropertiesinterval=60
  appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.FileLogger
  logfile=/usr/local/jboss6/standalone/log/spy.log
  excludebinary=false
  ```
- In the `standalone.xml` file, add the following system property to take the properties file

  ```xml
  <system-properties>
      ...
      <property name="spy.properties" value="/usr/local/jboss6/modules/com/p6spy/main/spy.properties"/>
      ...
  </system-properties>
  ```

  then modify the datasource to change the connection URL and use the new driver

  ```xml
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">
      <datasources>
          <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/myDataSource" pool-name="myDataSource" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
              <connection-url>jdbc:p6spy:mysql://my-host/my-database?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true</connection-url>
              <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class> <!-- I also tried changing it to the P6Spy class, as well as removing this line -->
              <driver>p6spy</driver>
              <security>
                  <user-name>credentials</user-name>
                  <password>credentials</password>
              </security>
              <validation>
                  <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                  <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                  <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
              </validation>
              <statement>
                  <prepared-statement-cache-size>25</prepared-statement-cache-size>
              </statement>
          </datasource>
          <drivers>
              <driver name="p6spy" module="com.p6spy">
                  <driver-class>com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver</driver-class>
              </driver>
              <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                  <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
              </driver>
              <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                  <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
              </driver>
          </drivers>
      </datasources>
  </subsystem>
  ```

Then I restart my server. In the logs JBoss recognizes the P6Spy driver and the datasource but when the application starts initializing an error occurs and the deployment stops.

```
15:24:47,923 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) Application startup failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name '[....]': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '[....]' defined in class path resource [MyConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.modeshape.jcr.JcrRepository]: Factory method '[....]' threw exception;
nested exception is MyException: An error has occurred while the application attempted to create the repository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:364) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1268) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:713) [spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530) [spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:123) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:666) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:353) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:300) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(JBossContextConfig.java:187) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3775) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '[....]' defined in class path resource [MyConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.modeshape.jcr.JcrRepository]: Factory method '[....]' threw exception;
nested exception is MyException: An error has occurred while the application attempted to create the repository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:211) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.modeshape.jcr.JcrRepository]: Factory method '[....]' threw exception;
nested exception is MyException: An error has occurred while the application attempted to create the repository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    ... 52 more
Caused by: MyException: An error has occurred while the application attempted to create the repository
    at [....]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    ... 53 more
Caused by: javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Error while starting '[....]' repository: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/myDataSource
    at org.modeshape.jcr.JcrRepository.login(JcrRepository.java:634) [modeshape-jcr-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.modeshape.jcr.JcrRepository.login(JcrRepository.java:598) [modeshape-jcr-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.modeshape.jcr.JcrRepository.login(JcrRepository.java:139) [modeshape-jcr-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at [....]
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.modeshape.persistence.relational.RelationalProviderException: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/myDataSource
    at org.modeshape.persistence.relational.DataSourceManager.newConnection(DataSourceManager.java:112) [modeshape-persistence-relational-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.modeshape.persistence.relational.DataSourceManager.<init>(DataSourceManager.java:53) [modeshape-persistence-relational-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.modeshape.persistence.relational.RelationalDb.<init>(RelationalDb.java:64) [modeshape-persistence-relational-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.modeshape.persistence.relational.RelationalProvider.getDB(RelationalProvider.java:34) [modeshape-persistence-relational-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.modeshape.persistence.relational.RelationalProvider.getDB(RelationalProvider.java:27) [modeshape-persistence-relational-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.modeshape.schematic.Schematic.getDbFromProvider(Schematic.java:91) [modeshape-schematic-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.modeshape.schematic.Schematic.lambda$getDb$9(Schematic.java:74) [modeshape-schematic-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1812) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at org.modeshape.schematic.Schematic.getDb(Schematic.java:76) [modeshape-schematic-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.modeshape.jcr.Environment.getDb(Environment.java:59) [modeshape-jcr-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.modeshape.jcr.JcrRepository$RunningState.<init>(JcrRepository.java:1037) [modeshape-jcr-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.modeshape.jcr.JcrRepository$RunningState.<init>(JcrRepository.java:939) [modeshape-jcr-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.modeshape.jcr.JcrRepository.doStart(JcrRepository.java:375) [modeshape-jcr-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.modeshape.jcr.JcrRepository.login(JcrRepository.java:632) [modeshape-jcr-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/myDataSource
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
    at org.modeshape.persistence.relational.DataSourceManager.newConnection(DataSourceManager.java:106) [modeshape-persistence-relational-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    ... 88 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/myDataSource
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:421)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:327)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:510)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:143)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000658: Unexpected throwable while trying to create a connection: null
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:421)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:453)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:425)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:354)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:356)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:304)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:834)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:379)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Wrong driver class [class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] for this connection URL [jdbc:p6spy:mysql://my-host/my-database?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:330)
    ... 98 more
```

This is an application that uses Modeshape 5.4.1.Final, the error happens when the repository bean tries to get a connection from the datasource.

Is there any configuration I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the element that was messing with the setup was the `<driver-class>` tag in the `<datasource>`. It should either have the P6Spy driver

```
<driver-class>com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver</driver-class>
```

or remove it altogether.

The reason this didn't work for me at the beginning is that I was editing the `standalone.xml` file and then reloading the configuration with `jboss-cli.sh --connect --command=:reload`. This works for most of the configuration changes but for this part is not enough. You *must shutdown the server and then starting it up again* in order for this change to be taken.